# Newly added function to the prototype of the constructor doesn't work when it's called on objects

Tags: javascript

```
function userCreator(name,score){
    const newUser = Object.create(userFunctions);
    newUser.name = name;
    newUser.score = score;
    return newUser;
}
userFunctions = {
  increment: function(){
      this.score++;
  }
};

userCreator.prototype.foo = function(){
    console.log("foo");
};

const user1 = userCreator("Phil",5);

user1.foo();
```

I try to add a function to my constructure  but when I add this function and call it with  `user1` it says `user1.foo()` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype you're assigning the object in `userCreator` isn't `userCreator.prototype`, it's `userFunctions`. So you'd add `foo` to that, not `userCreator.prototype`. Also, don't forget to declare `userFunctions`, at the moment your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

```js
function userCreator(name,score){
    const newUser = Object.create(userFunctions);
    newUser.name = name;
    newUser.score = score;
    return newUser;
}
const userFunctions = {  // *** Added const
  increment: function(){
      this.score++;
  }
};

userFunctions.foo = function(){ // *** `userFunctions`, not `userCreator.prototype`
    console.log("foo");
};

const user1 = userCreator("Phil",5);

user1.foo();
```

`userCreator.prototype` would be used automatically as the prototype of the new object if you were using `new userCreator` to create the object, but you're doing it manually with `Object.create(userFunctions)`.

Or alternately, get rid of `userFunctions` and use `userCreator.prototype` throughout:

```js
function userCreator(name,score){
    const newUser = Object.create(userCreator.prototype);
    newUser.name = name;
    newUser.score = score;
    return newUser;
}
userCreator.prototype.increment = function(){
    this.score++;
};

userCreator.prototype.foo = function(){
    console.log("foo");
};

const user1 = userCreator("Phil",5);

user1.foo();
```

Just for what it's worth, the version using `new`:

```js
function UserCreator(name,score){
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}
UserCreator.prototype.increment = function(){
    this.score++;
};

UserCreator.prototype.foo = function(){
    console.log("foo");
};

const user1 = new UserCreator("Phil",5);

user1.foo();
```

or, since you're already using ES2015+ features:

```js
class UserCreator {
    constructor(name,score){
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
    increment() {
        this.score++;
    }
}

// If for some reason you wanted to add it separately
// from the `class` definition
UserCreator.prototype.foo = function(){
    console.log("foo");
};

const user1 = new UserCreator("Phil",5);

user1.foo();
```

But doing it without `new` is fine, too, just add to the correct object.

Comment: Thanks man !  A short clarification : To be able to use X.prototype.functionname = function().....  syntax, i must use the new keyword or the syntactical sugar Classes right ? 

And it is not  possible at all to add .prototype.functionName  if I'm creating stuff manually like in my example.

Comment: @AtlasOkyanus - No, there's no reason you can't do `const newUser = Object.create(userCreator.prototype);` instead and not have `userFunctions` at all. `prototype` is just a property referring to an object, so if you want to use it directly, you can. I've added an example above. *"And it is not possible at all to add .prototype.functionName if I'm creating stuff manually like in my example."* You can add to the object `prototype` refers to when using *any* of the options above.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want the object prototype to inherit from the `userFunctions` object, in which case you should set

```
userCreator.prototype = Object.create(userFunctions);
```

*outside* of the constructor. You should also call `new` on the constructor, and don't return an object from it, in order for `<functionName>.prototype` to work correctly:

```js
function userCreator(name,score){
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}
userFunctions = {
  increment: function(){
      this.score++;
  }
};

userCreator.prototype = Object.create(userFunctions);
userCreator.prototype.foo = function(){
    console.log("foo");
};

const user1 = new userCreator("Phil",5);

user1.foo();
```

(technically, you *could* use `return this`, but it's superfluous)

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not use the `new` syntax in calling `userCreator` (and it isn't a function that returns an instance of its prototype), you don't use `userCreator` as a (standard) constructor. Therefore the created objects do not have `userCreator.prototype` as proto, and so any mutation of `userCreator.prototype` has no effect on your created object.

You seem to want to have User objects with UserFunctions. In ES6 syntax you would achieve that like this:

```js
class Scorer {
    constructor() {
        this.score = 0;
    }
    increment() {
        this.score++;
    }
}

class User extends Scorer {
    constructor(name, score) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
    foo() {
        console.log("foo");
    }
}

const user1 = new User("Phil", 5);

user1.foo();
```